# RemoteFileTemplate reads incomplete file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have the following test which uploads a file to an embedded apache ftp server and then checks if the file was correctly uploaded.

```
@Test
public void testUploadFile() {
    String fileName = "test.txt";
    ftpUploader.upload("/data/" + fileName);
    RemoteFileTemplate<FTPFile> template = new RemoteFileTemplate<>(this.ftpSessionFactory);
    FTPFile[] files = template.execute(session -> session.list(fileName));
    assertThat(files).hasSize(1);
    assertThat(files[0].getSize()).isEqualTo(FILE_CONTENT_SIZE);
}
```

I'm using Spring Integration. Via the RemoteFileTemplate I cehck if the file exists and has the correct size. If I execute this test in my IDE it works fine. The maven build including all the tests works as well. However, on Jenkins server the second assert fails

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<2[318796]L> but was:<2[290518]L>
```

What could be the reason for that? Does the template downloads the file even it is not fully uploaded? Actually this should not be the case as the ftpUploader appends the ending .writing to the file as long as it is still written. The FtpUpload looks as follows

```
 @MessagingGateway
public interface FtpUpload {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "ftpUploadChannel")
    void upload(String fileName);
}

@Bean
IntegrationFlow upload() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("ftpUploadChannel")
            .<String, File>transform(fileName -> new File(this.getClass().getResource(fileName).getFile()))
            .handle(Ftp.outboundAdapter(ftpSessionFactory())
                            .remoteDirectory(ftpRemoteDir)
                            .autoCreateDirectory(true)
                            .useTemporaryFileName(true)
            )
            .get();
}
```

Comment: Does Jenkins use the same OS as your dev desktop? Upload file to ftp may change the line breaks.

Comment: yes, this could be the problem..thanks for the hint

Comment: the difference between the expected and the acual size is exaclty the number of lines of the files. Thanks @longhua

Comment: I think, @longhua, it would be better to form an answer from your and close the Thread from all other guys with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most FTP clients use `ASCII` mode to transfer files by default. In this mode, line breaks will be changed. So in your case, the file size changes when running in different environments. The most probable cause is the line breaks are changed in one environment.